# Check that mock's method is called without any parameters passed (in phpunit)

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

In phpunit we can specify the method was called with particular

```
->with($this->equalTo('foobar'))
```

or any

```
->with($this->anything())
```

parameter.

But is there a way to specify that the method has been called without parameters at all?

This is the test I expect to fail:

```
public function testZ()
{
    $a = $this->getMock('q');

    $a->expects($this->once())
        ->method('z')
        ->with(); // <--- what constraint to specify here?

    $a->z(1);
}
```

**UPD**:

The question has theoretical nature, so I have no any real life example. Some case it could be useful I can think of right now is:

```
public function testMe($object)
{
    $object->foo();
}
```

And let's assume that `testMe` should (by design and by requirements) always call the method without parameters (assuming `foo()` has default ones). Because any non-default parameter (more precise: any parameter != to default one, which we don't know yet and which probably could change independently) in this case causes fatal consequences.

Comment: +1 I've spent a few minutes looking through the PHPUnit source over on github and it seems like `->with()` only works to actually specify parameters, not prohibit them. I can't really think of a scenario where verifying that no argument was passed is something you'd need to check for, though? I'd be interested to hear why you need to verify that no argument was sent. Passing an argument when none is expected won't break anything and can't you just pass in a NULL when there is an argument expected that can't be provided?

Comment: @rdlowrey: added an explanation update ;-)

Comment: @rdlowrey: `can't you just pass in a NULL when there is an argument expected that can't be provided` --- no you cannot. Method still could have optional parameters

Comment: Yeah ... I tried to re-edit that statement out of my comment once I read your update, but the 5 minute window had passed ;) I wish I could +5 the question because I'd like to know as well and from looking over the source I can't find a constraint that would work in this situation. You might need to go outside the scope of PHPUnit's built-in capabilities and extend the class under test with your own mock class that throws an exception or something if an argument gets passed to the method ...

Comment: @rdlowrey: I would accept `it is impossible` as a valid answer, as long as after some code research I don't see any possibility too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While rdlowrey is correct that `with()` doesn't make provisions for checking for no arguments passed, the problem doesn't lie with PHPUnit but PHP itself.

First, if your method doesn't provide default values, the interpreter will raise a fatal error if you don't pass any parameters. This is expected and not entirely relevant to the question at hand, but it's important to state up front.

Second, if your method *does* provide default values, calling the method without arguments will cause PHP to alter the call before PHPUnit gets involved to pass the defaults instead. Here's a simple test that demonstrates PHP inserting itself before PHP can check the parameters. It's key to realize that the mock class that PHP creates has the same signature as the mocked class--including the defaults.

```
class MockTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
        public function test() {
                $mock = $this->getMock('Foo', array('bar'));
                $mock->expects($this->once())
                     ->method('bar')
                     ->with()    // does nothing, but it doesn't matter
                     ->will($this->returnArgument(0));
                self::assertEquals('foobar', $mock->bar());  // PHP inserts 1 and 2
                // assertion fails because 1 != 'foobar'
        }
}

class Foo {
        public function bar($x = 1, $y = 2) {
                return $x + $y;
        }
}
```

This means you can verify that *either* nothing was passed or the default values were passed, but you cannot be more specific.

Can you get around this limitation? You can remove default values from arguments when overriding methods, so you should be able to create a subclass and mock it. Is it worth it? My initial gut reaction is that this is a huge code smell. Either your design or your tests are doing the Wrong Thing(tm).

If you can provide a real-world, concrete example where you actually need to do this kind of test, it's worth spending some time pondering a solution. Until then, I'm satisfied with the purely academic answer of "don't do that." :)

Comment: +1 for the clarification. I agree that it seems like a code smell ... I haven't seen a real-world application for it and it seems like an issue that a simple refactoring would avoid.

Comment: "Until then, I'm satisfied with the purely academic answer of "don't do that." :)" --- I do agree that I cannot think of real world example and that is why I stated "The question has theoretical nature" - so I just asked about theoretical possibility of doing that without explanations why I need that ;-)

Comment: @zerkms - Sounds like a great new question. :)

Comment: @David Harkness: nah. All the people interested in the answer are competent enough to browse its sources :-)

Answer (score 4):

PHPUnit mock objects can only use the `->with()` constraint method to verify that the count or respective values of passed parameters match those passed to the mocked method when invoked. You can't use it to require that *no arguments* are passed to the mock method.

The mock verification process specifically checks that the passed parameter count and the associated values are compatible with those passed to the `with` constraint. Also, as you've probably seen, specifying the `with` constraint without any values won't work either; if `with` receives no parameters it won't add any parameter constraints for verification.

You can see the actual [`PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_Parameters::verify`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src/Framework/MockObject/Matcher/Parameters.php) method used to verify mock method parameters in the linked github source.

If validation of no passed arguments is a requirement you'll need to specify your own mock class to verify such a condition outside the PHPUnit mocking capabilities.

Comment: Without editing this answer I want to add that I've come to this conclusion not from an impossibly nuanced understanding of the PHPUnit internals, but from a long time searching the relevant source code in an attempt to accomplish the question's stated goal. I believe the linked source code is proof that it's not possible, but if someone can figure out a way to make it work, please share.