# Phpunit, with() is buggy?

Tags: php, phpunit

class to be tested:

```
class Arithmetic
{
    public function mockme($param1 = 0, $param2 = 0)
    {
        echo 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF';die;
    }

    public function mockme2()
    {
        $this->mockme('a', 'b');
    }
}
```

to test it:

```
public function testMock()
{
    $mock = $this->getMock('Arithmetic', array('mockme'));
    $mock->expects($this->once())->method('mockme')->with();

    $mock->mockme2();
}
```

now it passes however not supposed to be. Why? The `with()` is given. I expect that no parameter must be passed to `mockme()` - so `with()` shouldve expected empty parameters. But now its like I didnt set it at all.
In other words: if I set `with(1,4)` its a must to pass 1,4. If I set `with('a')`, its a must to pass 'a'. If I set nothing `with()` its a must not to pass anything (but it regards it like I didnt set any `with()`)

Comment: Related: [Check that mock's method is called without any parameters passed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9478093/797303)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check that mock's method is called without any parameters passed (in phpunit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475705/check-that-mocks-method-is-called-without-any-parameters-passed-in-phpunit)