# How does it work withAnyArguments() method?

Tags: mocking, phpunit

These are my class:

```
class Car
{
    public function getStarted(Actions $actions)
    {
        $actions->run('go');
    }
}
```

/...

```
class Actions
{

    public function run($arg)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have this test:

```
$Car = new Car();
$ActionsMock = $this->createMock('Actions');

$Actions->expects($this->once())
                        ->method('run')
                        ->withAnyParameters()
                        ->willReturn('xy');

$Car->getStarted($Actions);
```

And I don't get an error, whether I call to `withAnyArguments()`, so... should give me error, because `run()`  method has an argument.

The Question is: work like this or I'm think bad?

Comment: If you substitute  `->withAnyParameters()` with `->with('go')` all go fine but if you use `->with('stay')` it will fail the expectation

Comment: or check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475705/check-that-mocks-method-is-called-without-any-parameters-passed-in-phpunit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withAnyParameters()` is the default and it means that there is no specific expectation with the parameters. It verifies just the correct count of parameters while testing but nothing more.

And in your example you have the correct parameter count.

However, for me in your example this looks fine as the parameter is a hard-coded string hidden in **Car**, so this is an implementation detail that should not be unit-tested as it is transparent to the public interface.

So for a test of **Car**'s public interface this check is technically not necessary (this can sound opinionated). That is because the mock object is just to assist testing the object. If such a check against a concrete string is considered necessary, it should be tested in the unit-test of **Actions** as **Car** is only a consumer which can expect **Actions** to work for real-world situations and can be better covered there.

If you still want to test that internal detail in the unit-test of **Car**, you can do like suggested in the first comment and check the configuration with the concrete parameter value, here "`go`":

```
$Actions
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('run')
    ->with('go') # <---
    ->willReturn('xy')
    ;
```

That will test your expected call of **Actions** run method with that specific parameter. Most likely this is what reflects your intention and this can be useful for configuration testing or testing internals (e.g. sanity check or document expected usage of the **Actions** object by **Car**).